# Application unresponsive to network messages (idle?)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, adobe

I have two applications, one running on iOS and the other on desktop. They communicate between each other using NetConnection (rtmfp). The strange thing is that the desktop application when non-active (in background) stalls the communication. For example on iOS I have a button and when clicked it sends a message containing a URL. The desktop app then responds with a navigateToURL request. This works fine but sometimes when I don't actively use the desktop then the app does not respond UNLESS I MOVE THE MOUSE ... Then the URL opens in a new tab in Chrome. I already tried setting:

```
nativeApplication.executeInBackground = true;
nativeApplication.idleThreshold = 86400;
nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
```

in the desktop application's preinitialize handler but this does not solve the issue. Anyone have an idea what could cause this and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Desktop application runs on Mac OSX by the way

Comment: `nativeApplication.systemIdleMode` is not supported on Deskop operating systems.  I suspect Mac OS may be responsible for making your app non-responsive after a period of time.  Have you tried your desktop app on Windows environment or another computer running Mac OS X?

Comment: I did some more testing and found that the OS doesn't sleep but the AIR app if inactive does sleep. Messages are received but not processed until I re-activate the AIR app. Any pointers on how to keep the connection alive in an AIR app that doesn't have OS focus?

Answer (score 0):

Issue found and solved. App Nap is the culprit, see http://apache-flex-users.2333346.n4.nabble.com/Application-in-background-throttle-issues-td11976.html#a11978 for details